# If $f(x)$ has a minimum positive period, then is $f(x^2)$ not periodic?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

We all know that $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ is not periodic, so I want to strengthen the proposition to any function which has a minimum positive period.

My idea is that let $f(0)=0$, and we can find all the zero points in $[0,T]$. I tried to prove that the zero points are dense and maybe we can find a contradiction.

Maybe there is a counterexample. I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Also see See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282756/periodic-function-f-for-which-fx2-is-periodic-too.